LU decomposition on a sparse rectangular matrix in R
MATLAB is able to perform LU decomposition on a sparse rectangular matrix using [L, U, P, Q] = lu(A) but there is no R package to do so yet.
Trying to use Matrix::lu() on a sparse matrix in R returns an error complaining that the matrix must be square.
Is there any analogue of MATLAB's LU decomposition on a rectangular matrix that is not full rank in R? To clarify, this is not about memory issues - if I embed it in an identity matrix (see this question) then Matrix::lu() complains about the matrix being singular, while MATLAB's lu() happily proceeds.
The problem I'm trying to solve is to implement a particular econometric estimator in R that needs the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse.
pracma's Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse fails because the matrix is too large.
Getting a Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse of a large sparse matrix is also unsolved apparently, see here.
My matrix has more than one 1 in any given row and column.

Can you afford to convert your matrix into a dense matrix, or is that too impractical?

?qr ?rankMatrix

Try pracma::lu().

@jay.sf, ?pracma::lu seems to say that the input has to be square ...

I've been trying to make something comparable with RcppEigen, since Eigen can apparently perform sparse LU decomposition on general matrices but I'm having no luck in converting the output to plain sparse matrices.

@BenBolker fair enough...

maybe post your partial solution as a (partial) answer and see if someone can help you move forward from there?

I did and I also added the problem I am trying to solve.

Maybe this could be of some help

Both embedding it into an identity matrix and doing LU decomposition on A'A result in an out of memory or near-singular error while MATLAB happily proceeds. The way I was taught LU decomposition in my numerical analysis class in college only made sense for square matrices, so I would like to understand what MATLAB is doing behind the scenes in addition to being able to do that in R.

I'm happy to re-open if you can show why the linked answer won't work for you -- other than memory constraints which is a separate issue

This is about reproducing Matlab's lu in R. It's not really going out of memory, it's reporting it as singular, which it is - but we want it to do a rank-revealing factorization. I'm getting closer using UMFPACK, I'll edit the question if I can.

@CarlWitthoft I found a solution and will post it as an answer if you re-open the question. My solution solves both the issue of doing a LU factorization on a singular matrix and that of computing the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse on a sparse matrix with more than one 1 in a given row/column, both of which are unsolved in the two related questions.

@kmf  Nice work!  I re-opened for you

Solved. The following code uses UMFPACK, which is the same library MATLAB uses. To get the right elements, we need to add Control[UMFPACK_SCALE] = 0;. Then we need to fix the size of the resulting U matrix in R.
#include <suitesparse/umfpack.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List sparseLU(const std::vector<int> &Ap, const std::vector<int> &Ai, const std::vector<double> &Ax) {
  int n = Ap.size() - 1;
  int m = *std::max_element(Ai.begin(), Ai.end()) + 1;
  int nnz = Ax.size();
  double Control [UMFPACK_CONTROL], Info [UMFPACK_INFO];
  umfpack_di_defaults(Control);
  Control[UMFPACK_PRL] = 2;
  Control[UMFPACK_SCALE] = 0;
  Control[UMFPACK_STRATEGY] = UMFPACK_STRATEGY_SYMMETRIC;

  void *symbolic, *numeric;
  int status;
  status = umfpack_di_symbolic(m, n, Ap.data(), Ai.data(), Ax.data(), &symbolic, Control, Info);
  if (status != UMFPACK_OK) {
    umfpack_di_report_status(Control, status);
    if (status < 0) {
      Rcpp::stop("umfpack_di_symbolic failed with status %d", status);
    }
  }

  status = umfpack_di_numeric(Ap.data(), Ai.data(), Ax.data(), symbolic, &numeric, Control, Info);
  if (status != UMFPACK_OK) {
    umfpack_di_report_status(Control, status);
    if (status < 0) {
      Rcpp::stop("umfpack_di_numeric failed with status %d", status);
      umfpack_di_free_symbolic(&symbolic);
    }
  }

  umfpack_di_free_symbolic(&symbolic);

  int lnz, unz, nz_udiag;
  status = umfpack_di_get_lunz(&lnz, &unz, &m, &n, &nz_udiag, numeric);
  if (status != UMFPACK_OK) {
    umfpack_di_report_status(Control, status);
    if (status < 0) {
      Rcpp::stop("umfpack_di_get_lunz failed with status %d", status);
      umfpack_di_free_numeric(&numeric);
    }
  }


  std::vector<int> Lp(m+1), Lj(lnz), Up(n+1), Ui(unz), P(m), Q(n);
  std::vector<double> Lx(lnz), Ux(unz), D(std::min(m, n)), Rs(m);
  int do_recip;

  status = umfpack_di_get_numeric(Lp.data(), Lj.data(), Lx.data(), Up.data(), Ui.data(), Ux.data(), P.data(), Q.data(), D.data(), &do_recip, Rs.data(), numeric);
  if (status != UMFPACK_OK) {
    umfpack_di_report_status(Control, status);
    if (status < 0) {
      umfpack_di_free_numeric(&numeric);
      Rcpp::stop("umfpack_di_get_numeric failed with status %d", status);
    }
  }

  umfpack_di_free_numeric(&numeric);

  Rcpp::List ret = Rcpp::List::create(
      Rcpp::Named("L") = Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("j") = Lj, Rcpp::Named("p") = Lp, Rcpp::Named("x") = Lx),
      Rcpp::Named("U") = Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("i") = Ui, Rcpp::Named("p") = Up, Rcpp::Named("x") = Ux),
      Rcpp::Named("P") = P,
      Rcpp::Named("Q") = Q
      );


  return ret;
}

Then we can load it in R like this
# A is a sparseMatrix() from package Matrix
LUPQ <- sparseLU(A@p, A@i, A@x) 
n <- ncol(A)
L <- sparseMatrix(j = LUPQ$L$j, p = LUPQ$L$p, x = LUPQ$L$x, index1 = FALSE) 
U <- sparseMatrix(i = LUPQ$U$i, p = LUPQ$U$p, x = LUPQ$U$x, index1 = FALSE, dims = c(n, n))
Q <- sparseMatrix(i = LUPQ$Q + 1, j = 1:length(LUPQ$Q), x = 1)

